# Get Div property using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm able to get anchor's property `href` using `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` by using following code

```
foreach($page->find('a') as $anchor){
    echo trim(strip_tags($anchor->href));  
}
```

This is working absolutely fine.
But Here is the issue, Now I've to get the `data-cursor` property of `div`

```
<div class = 'someClass' data-cursor = '4515314844'>
    some contents here..
</div>
```

but if I try the same approach, as mentioned above, this throws an error

```
foreach($page->find('div') as $div){
    echo trim(strip_tags($div->data-cursor));  
}

Error: Use of undefined constant cursor - assumed 'cursor'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the hypenated property properly, you need to do this:

```
$div->{'data-cursor'}
```

Would look like this:

```
echo trim(strip_tags($div->{'data-cursor'}));
```

Comment: this is cool, I want to vote it up.. but I've not enough rating to vote it up :(

Comment: perhaps it would go up if some of you give this question an up vote

Comment: Thanks Man.. I'm still unable to vote it up :(
BTW many thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Error: Use of undefined constant cursor - assumed 'cursor'
```

That should tell you that PHP isn't parsing your code correctly because of the hyphen. It's reading 'data' then the hyphen is throwing it off. Try surrounding it like this:

```
$div->{'data-cursor'}
```